# How do I change Simplescan's default email?

Tags: linux-mint, email, thunderbird, scanner

I found one other person with this issue from long ago. I'm currently:

```
Mint 17.1/64/i5/16GB RAM
3.13.0-37-generic
```

In SS, if I choose, `"scan to email"-->` it opens Chromium? I'd like to know if I can get it to point to my Thunderbird email? If so, what are the steps?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try and set your preferred email programm to Thunderbird. I use Debian with xfce and if I go to Preferences->Preferred Applications and set it to Evolution, Simple Scan opens mails with Evolution. I am sure there is a comparable approach in Mint.

Comment: I had already checked that (I should have said) and TB is also my only email program...The funny thing is that my "preferred" browser is FF...but Simple Scan seems to prefer Chromium- lol.

Comment: Okay, it's now April 2017, nearly a year has passed & still no answer to this question? I can't be the only one to experience this? As previously stated, Thunderbird is the only email program on my PC (Linux Mint 17) & it IS the default mail handler. So, why is Chromium opening when I use, "email"?